# equivalent of `command | some_command || true` in windows powershell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

I have to convert some commands which are used in linux based system to be used in windows based system.

One such command is,
`execute_command_1 | command_2 || true`

I am new to operating systems. I will be really grateful if someone can explain to me what this command does and what will be the powershell (powershell 5.1, specifically) equivalent of this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.3) operator, e.g.:

```
> $true -or $false
True
```

Comment: can you also tell me what ```true``` does in linux?

Comment: @ShubhamDeshpnde `|| true` means OR true, which basically ensures that that line of code is always successful